# Delphi: how to identify which panel called Form2

Tags: delphi, panel

I have 16 `TPanels` on `Form1` and `OnDblClick` event they call `Form2`  ( `form2.Show;` ). working with `Form2`, I want to know, which of panel(TPanel name) have called `Form2`

PS: using Tag property can identify tag number, but I need edit1.text  to show the name of panel

Comment: Perhaps use the `Sender` argument of the `OnDblClick` event handler. That `Sender` argument contains a reference to the object that invoked the event. Although we don't know whether your panels all share the same event handler or not, because you didn't provide a [mcve] which would have removed all doubt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several possible solutions.

One of then is to add a string property to Form2 and set the value of the panel OnDblClick event before calling Form2.Show.

Another one is the create a new function in Form2 that takes a string argument which is the panel name, save that value to a form's field and call Show. From the panel's OnDblClick, call the function instead of Show, passing the panel's name.